# How does Vandermonde's Identity take care of the cases where $r>m,n$?

Tags: combinatorics

I am studying Vandermonde's Identity,namely $$ \sum_{k=0}^r \dbinom{m}{k} \cdot \dbinom{n}{r-k}=\dbinom{m+n}{r}$$

and I can't understand how this sum takes care also of the case where $r >m,n$.

I read in my book that in these cases the sum of these terms will be $0$ ,but I don't see why.

Take for example the case where $m,n=1$ and $r=2$,then I have

$$\dbinom{1}{0}\cdot\dbinom{1}{2} +\dbinom{1}{1} \cdot \dbinom{1}{1} +\dbinom{1}{2} \cdot \dbinom{1}{0}=\dbinom{2}{2}=1$$

How do the terms $\dbinom{1}{0}\cdot\dbinom{1}{2} +\dbinom{1}{2} \cdot \dbinom{1}{0} =0 $ ?

If I were to apply blindly the algebra I would get $\cfrac{1}{2!\cdot(-1)!} +\cfrac{1}{2! \cdot(-1 !)} $ ,now how do I deal with this ?

(This is probably a stupid question to ask,however I didn't find anything previously on the internet )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned terms have value $0$ *by definition*.

Interpret $\binom{m}{k}$ as the number of subsets of set $\{1,\dots,m\}$ that have cardinality $k$.

If $k\in\{0,1,\dots,m\}$ then $\binom{m}{k}=\frac{m!}{k!(m-k)!}$ and  $\binom{m}{k}=0$ otherwise.

Comment: Oh ,thanks I thought I was making some dumb mistake ...